# KMS Key: The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-kms

I've currently got a KMS key module that creates a key and assigns a secret owner and manager. The owner is the root account and the manager is another account with poweruseraccess policy attached to it. When I try to create the kms key or test the module, I receive the error saying: **The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future**. I can confirm that both accounts exists.

Below is a copy of my code:

```
module "secrets_manager_policy" {
  source      = "../../"
  description = "A KMS key with managed resource-policy."
  resource_policy_statements = {
    SecretOwner = {
      actions   = ["kms:*"]
      resources = ["*"]
      principals = {
        AWS = [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000:root"
        ]
      }
    }
    SecretManagers = {
      actions = [
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey"
      ]
      resources = ["*"]
      principals = {
        AWS = [
          "arn:aws:iam::00000000:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_123445"
        ]
      }
      conditions = {
        StringLike = {
          "kms:ViaService" = [
            "secretsmanager.*.amazonaws.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the error mention the line of the code which is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you please verify whether the IAM role/user creating the KMS key has the `kms:PutKeyPolicy` permission (since the Principal in the key policy is the Root). More explanation is [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/update-key-policy-future).